# Why is Google colab TPU slower than CPU or GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, tpu

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras import models, layers
from keras.utils import to_categorical

import tensorflow as tf



tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()
print('Running on TPU ', tpu.cluster_spec().as_dict()['worker'])

tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)

strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(tpu)
print("REPLICAS: ", strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)




with strategy.scope():
  network = models.Sequential()
  network.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(28 * 28,)))
  network.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

  network.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

 
  
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28 * 28))
train_images = train_images.astype('float32') / 255

test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28 * 28))
test_images = test_images.astype('float32') / 255        

train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)

network.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, batch_size=128)

test_loss, test_acc = network.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)

print("test_acc: ", test_acc)
```

Result:

```
Running on TPU  ['10.123.181.34:8470']
WARNING:tensorflow:TPU system grpc://10.123.181.34:8470 has already been initialized. Reinitializing the TPU can cause previously created variables on TPU to be lost.
WARNING:tensorflow:TPU system grpc://10.123.181.34:8470 has already been initialized. Reinitializing the TPU can cause previously created variables on TPU to be lost.
INFO:tensorflow:Initializing the TPU system: grpc://10.123.181.34:8470
INFO:tensorflow:Initializing the TPU system: grpc://10.123.181.34:8470
INFO:tensorflow:Clearing out eager caches
INFO:tensorflow:Clearing out eager caches
INFO:tensorflow:Finished initializing TPU system.
INFO:tensorflow:Finished initializing TPU system.
WARNING:absl:`tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy` is deprecated, please use  the non experimental symbol `tf.distribute.TPUStrategy` instead.
INFO:tensorflow:Found TPU system:
INFO:tensorflow:Found TPU system:
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Cores: 8
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Cores: 8
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Workers: 1
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Workers: 1
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Cores Per Worker: 8
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Cores Per Worker: 8
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:0, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:0, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:1, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:1, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:2, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:2, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:3, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:3, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:4, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:4, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:5, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:5, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:6, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:6, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:7, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:7, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU_SYSTEM:0, TPU_SYSTEM, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU_SYSTEM:0, TPU_SYSTEM, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, XLA_CPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, XLA_CPU, 0, 0)
REPLICAS:  8
Epoch 1/5
469/469 [==============================] - 11s 18ms/step - loss: 0.4224 - accuracy: 0.8787
Epoch 2/5
469/469 [==============================] - 8s 18ms/step - loss: 0.1089 - accuracy: 0.9675
Epoch 3/5
469/469 [==============================] - 9s 18ms/step - loss: 0.0695 - accuracy: 0.9789
Epoch 4/5
469/469 [==============================] - 8s 17ms/step - loss: 0.0485 - accuracy: 0.9856
Epoch 5/5
469/469 [==============================] - 8s 18ms/step - loss: 0.0345 - accuracy: 0.9898
313/313 [==============================] - 7s 18ms/step - loss: 0.0684 - accuracy: 0.9791
test_acc:  0.9790999889373779
```

It is slower than CPU and GPU.
Why is it slow? And how can I fix it?

Comment: My first guess would be that distributing data over 8 TPUs and communicating back is expensive and takes more time than calculation themselves, especially for such shallow network

Comment: does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65307741/why-is-google-colab-tpu-as-slow-as-my-computer/65307818#65307818 help ?

Comment: @Andrey That article really helps. I changed batch size from 128 to 1024 and now training is as fast as GPU. Thanks!